# Execute an array of value in Linq to return the specific data in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

**Background:**

I'm using Linq to SQL class to connect with my database.

I have set up *MyProjectRepo.cs*

```
public IList<SQLTable> GetAllTopicById(int functionId)
{
  var query = from tb in _dataContext.table select tb;
  var content = query.ToList<SQLTbale>();
  return content;
}
```

*IMyProjectRepo.cs*

```
IList<SQLTable> GetAllTopicById(int functionId);
```

And *MyProjectModel.cs*

```
public MyProjectModel()
  {
   AvailableFunction = new List<MultiSelectList>();
   AvailableTopic = new List<MultiSelectList>();
  }
  // 1st List box that works properly 
   public IList<MultiSelectList> AvailableFunction{get;set;}
  // 2nd list box that is related with this Question
   public IList<MultiSelectList> AvailableTopic{get;set;}
```

These setups are working properly and they can get the data I want from SQL.
The `functionId` is used in `ListBoxFor(model=>model.FunctionID, new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableFunction))` to retrieve an array of functionIDs and then pass them to the next `ListBoxFor(model=>model.TopicID, new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableTopic))`.

Since I want to have real MultiSelect function, I wrote a Jquery to collect all selects for functionIDs and put them as an array and used Ajax(I did research that Ajax call needs to set `traditional:true` while passing an array of value) to pass them to my controller.

Here is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetAllTopic(int[] functionId)
      {
        foreach(int i in functionId) 
        {
         var alltopic = _repository.getAllTopicById(i)
         var result = (from at in alltopic
                       where at.function_id = i
                       select new
                       {
                        id= at.topic_id,
                        topicname = at.topic_name
                       }).Distinct().ToList();
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    return View();// If I don't write this return, it will say "not all code paths return a
          // value" Is this because I wrote everything in that Foreach loop?
         }
```

**So the Question is:**

This `foreach` loop only executes the first value of the array that is passed from ajax. For example: Ajax returns 3 values in the array (functionId{ 1,3,5}), and when I put a break point in controller I can see this array in `foreach(int i in functionId{1,3,5})` but it only executes one time(i=1). How can I make this controller work so that it can execute every value in the array to get the data I want?

The reason I did this way is that sometimes those functionIds have some same topic_names and I don't want the multiselectlist has those duplicated names.

For example:

{functionId=1 topic_name=topic1,topic2,topic3}

{functionId=2 topic_name=topic2 topic3 topic4}

{functionId=3 topic_name= topic1, topic3,topic5}

If user select functionId{1,2,3}, what I'd like to see in return is {topic_name= topic1,2,3,4,5} not {topic_name=1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5}

I know that is easy to achieve in SQL, just type `where functionId In(1,2,3)` ,but since I'm using Linq and JQueryAJAX in MVC, I guess it's better to do match and comparing function in repository than writing complex Linq in `MyProjectRepo.cs`.Actually,it's no help because model doesn't talk directly with Ajax.

Here is my logic: Linq retures the entire table to my model and pass it to `_repository.GetAllTopicById`, and I declare `var alltopic = this _repository.GetAllTopicById` in controller, then I can match those ids that collected from Ajax with this controller.

I hope the whole sequence I wrote can be understood by everyone and if anyone has any solution to make this work or any question about some parts I wrote, please drop a line below. Any reply will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Kevin

Comment: Why are you returning a value from inside your for each?

Comment: Use distinct method to get rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using for each. Can you try this code?

```
[Test]
    public void ArrayValueInLinq()
    {
        int[] functionId=new int[]{1,2};
        IList<SQLTable> alltopic=new List<SQLTable>
        {
            new SQLTable
            {
               topic_id=1,
               topic_name="john"
            },
            new SQLTable
            {
               topic_id=1,
               topic_name="john"
            },
            new SQLTable
            {
               topic_id=2,
               topic_name="Tomal"
            },
            new SQLTable
            {
               topic_id=1,
               topic_name="john"
            }
        };
        var result = (from at in alltopic
                      select new
                      {
                          id = at.topic_id,
                          topicname = at.topic_name
                      }).Where(p=>functionId.Contains(p.id)).Distinct().ToList();
    }
    public class SQLTable
    {
        public int topic_id { get; set; }
        public string topic_name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: WOW man you really solved the problem I have been confusing for a week. I took your`.Where(p=>functionId.Contains(p.id))` and because I need to let `p.id` equals `function_id` so I declare a `fid= at.function_id` and tranfer your code to `.Where(p=>functionId.Contains(p.fid))`. And that works! Thank you so much for solving this problem for me!

Comment: I have another question about `.Where()` clause. How can I write if I want more than one conditions in `.Where()`, such as `.Where(p=>functionId.Contains(p.fid) && t=>topicId.Contains(t.tid))`? but the function seems not like the way I use "&&" or "||".

Comment: you can use like this p=>functionId.Contains(p.id) && p.id==30